# Voice recognition on arduino or raspberry pi?

Tags: hardware, arduino, speech-recognition

I am trying to do a project with voice recognition. Which platform is better for voice recognition Arduino or Raspberry Pi? And why?

Comment: Have you already read http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10384/speech-processing-on-the-raspberry-pi/10392#10392 ?

Comment: yes. The point of my question is to get the difference between arduino and raspberry pi on voice recognition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go so far to say that the computational power of an arduino would be quite a limit to voice recognition. [Bitvoicer](http://www.bitsophia.com/BitVoicer.aspx) for example uses the arduino to sample the speech but not to process and recognice it. It sends the stream to a more powerful system to do the recognition part.

The Pi on the other hand is powerful enough to do all the processing itself as this [excellent answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10392/19949) points out.

If the voice commands to be distinguished are very rudimentary only (as your other [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32042/19949) suggests) it might be possible to get something done with the arduino. But I think that it will be bordering self mortification.

Comment: "If the voice commands to be distinguished are very rudimentary only" not exactly, i will add some features. if the head unit that controls the mouse movement stop working, there will be an option to control it by voice.

Comment: In this case I'd strongly vote to not use an arduino!

Comment: About the sensors.I won't use the berryIMU because it's a combined chip.
i have to use them in separate. Do you have any suggestion?